# Terminology question : "half smooth, half topological" fibre bundle

Tags: terminology, differential-topology, fiber-bundles

First, I know (or I think I know...) the definition of fiber bundle, be it in the smooth or topological category. Here is my situation, which is kind of between the two: I have a smooth manifold $E$, a topological manifold $X$, a continuous surjective map $p : E \rightarrow B$ such that in local charts, $p$ is a linear projection.

If both $E$ and $B$ were topological manifolds, that would be equivalent to saying that $p$ is a fibre bundle in the topological category. If both $E$ and $B$ where both smooth, $p$ would be a fibre bundle in the smooth category.

Is there a standard terminology for my "half-way through" case ? (I emphasize that my property is stronger than being a (topological) fibre bundle).

Comment: Disregard my previous dumb comment. I'm not aware of any special terminology, would "vector bundle with smooth total space" suit your needs? But I think the condition is weird, because you can't require $p$ to be smooth, so you're essentially disregarding the smooth structure of $E$ here. It's pretty much the same thing as a topological vector bundle, and a particular smooth structure on the total space with no interactions between the two.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi I didn't see your dumb comment :)
I think there is an interaction though, because $p$ is written in smooth coordinates in $E$

Comment: (to be more precise, if you just pick a topological fibre bundle $p$ and then an unrelated smooth structure on $E$, it might be that the charts in which you can straighten $p$ to a linear map are not in the smaller smooth atlas